# JAVA RMI - start a tutorial

Tags: java, exception, connection, rmi

I'm trying to start a Java RMI Tutorial and I'm getting a "java.rmi.ConnectException" and I don't know if I'm missing something or if this is something related to the pubblic connection of my University.

I have 3 independent projects: the interface,Server,Client.

Obviously Server and Client on their dependencies have the interface and they can't see each other.

Here is the code:

Interface

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface Hello extends Remote {
    String sayHello() throws RemoteException;
}
```

Client

```
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
public class Client {
    private Client() {}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String host = (args.length < 1) ? null : args[0];
        try {
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host);
            Hello stub = (Hello) registry.lookup("Hello");
            String response = stub.sayHello();
            System.out.println("response: " + response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Client exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Server

```
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class Server implements Hello {

    public Server() {}
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            Server obj = new Server();
            Hello stub = (Hello) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj, 0);
            // Bind the remote object's stub in the registry
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            registry.bind("Hello", stub);
            System.err.println("Server ready");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Server exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In the Server and Client projects, outside the src folder, I've placed two indentical files called "sc.policy"

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Am I missing something important ?
In the tutorial is mentioned to start the registry but I don't understand what that means.

---

Exception:

```
Client exception: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 130.251.215.124; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 130.251.215.124; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:342)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at Client.main(Client.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
```

Comment: Can you post the exception stacktrace?

Comment: how do you launch your server and your client? Have you started the `rmiregistry`?

Comment: I think that's the problem, in the last line of my post I wrote "In the tutorial is mentioned to start the registry but I don't understand what that means."

Is it something that I need to launch from a shell ?

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/running.html)

Comment: If your goal is only to test, simply replace `Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry()` with `Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT)` in your `Server`, then you won't even need the `rmiregistry` anymore, simply start the `Server`, then start the `Client`.

Comment: @Pickeroll If that was the problem you would also have had a `ConnectException` when starting the server, in `Registry.bind()`.